# Naming convention for a function that's never dispatched by user in R

Tags: r, naming-conventions

I have a function that I recently refactored. It used to look like this.

```
annotate <- function(param1, param2, param3) {
# setup
# Do work
# Do work but with a slight twist
}
```

Seeing copy-pasted code bugged me so I refactored it to this:

```
annotate <- function(param1, param2, param3) {
# setup
annotateFxn(setup, param1, param2)
annotateFxn(setup, param1, param2, param3)
}

annotateFxn(setup, param1, param2, param3 = NULL) {
# Do work, account for if param3 is NULL
}
```

I do not intend anyone to call `annotateFxn` directly. Is there a naming convention in R for what I might call this instead of its placeholder, `annotateFxn`?

I know that in Python, the convention is to place underscores in front of a function you don't want a user to call, but underscores can't start a variable name in R. Is there anything close to a convention for this?

Comment: @akrun Is using a default for optional parameters not the recommended method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common convention in many packages is to start internal functions like with a dot ala `.annotate_helper()`. You can also consider not exporting this function so that it is not accessible to users unless they use the `:::` operator: `package:::.annotate_helper()`.

Comment: I'd strengthen that:  @Jeff *should not* export that internal function.

Comment: @user2554330 ok. What's the syntax to produce an internal function and stop it from being imported with `source()`?

Comment: Are you writing a package or just a script? If it's a package, you need to explicitly export functions, so just don't export them.

If you are writing just a script, you have two options. First, if you put a leading `.` in the function name, then the object will be hidden by default (e.g., it won't show in RStudio's Environment pane or when `ls()` is run unless showing hidden values is specified). Second, you could define the internal function *inside* the main function, rather than in the global environment. This is fairly common. Look at `stats:::plot.lm` for an example.

Comment: @Jeff:  You should be putting your code in a package, even if you never intend to distribute it to anyone else.  This makes a large number of tools available to you that you just can't use in a script.  It also enforces some discipline on your writing, especially if you work to pass `R CMD check`.  In the package, you should explicitly export the things that you want available outside the package.